# What's the difference between "show arp no-resolve" and "show arp" in Juniper?

Tags: juniper, arp

What's the difference between `show arp no-resolve` and `show arp`?

If I add the `no-resolve`, what's the difference of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`no-resolve` indicates you don't want to do DNS lookups for every IP address in the ARP table:

```
teun@juniper> show arp ?
Possible completions:
  ...
  no-resolve           Don't attempt to print addresses symbolically
```

So with `no-resolve` only see IP adresses, which can be a *lot* faster when you have a lot of ARP entries.

Answer (score 0):

show arp :display and modify the ARP
show ARP noresolve : only display the ARP

Comment: `show arp` does *not* modify the ARP table. Other than that, it's unclear what exactly it is you're trying to tell here. Please consider improving your answer.